# Bootstrap styles not loading in angular 10

Tags: css, angular, visual-studio, bootstrap-4

I am working on a project where I am using angular 10 and trying to use Bootstrap library, but the issue is BootStrap styles are not loading.

In package.json I can see bootstrap dependency there.

```
"bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
```

I tried to debug in every possible way but not able to figure out yet as I am new to Bootstrap.

Don't want to see my button like this.

[image: Currently, the button is looking like this]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using bootstrap in angular there are several ways of adding it in. The most effective approach for me is to run `ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` in the root of your project which will add required data in your angular.json and your package.json.

I should note that you have to have Angular Cli version greater than 9.

Comment: Yes CLI version is 10.0.3.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Could you mark this answer as the answer so other people with the same problem know where to look?

Answer (score 2):

**if u add bootstrap while sever is already running it won't affect.. we should restart the server then it will work .. if not check the below steps**

make sure u have this code in ur angular.json file

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

to install bootstrap and jquery use this cmds ..first go to ur app diectory then open terminal hit this cmds

`npm install bootstrap@latest --save`

`npm install jquery@latest --save`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after restarting the server it just works fine for me. I installed it from the npm using the npm install command.

Comment: If you installed using npm install command during the server already running, this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Include Bootstrap link `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">` in index.html file and recompile the apps it will work   or second way is to include your bootstrap assets path in angular.json -> projects -> architect -> styles

Comment: Tried doing it, still not working. Any other walk around?

Comment: it's only add the style in the part of styles in the angular.json. If you only work with ng-bootstrap (for me the best option), download bootstrap.min.css, copy in a folder of your application and indicate in angular.json

Answer (score 0):

Another walk around to this,
If bootstrap is successfully installed and still Bootstrap styles not loading , just add

```
node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

in your angular.json.

Styles will be visible now.

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting to see the bootstrap.css in the html `<head>` section like everyone was saying for older versions, but instead it was hidden, bundled in the styles.css file in the browser.

Only these steps were required:

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

And in angular.json, unde build (not test):

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

Now run `ng serve` again

Answer (score 0):

Go to the package.json and check if the versions are right.sometimes you got a bad combination when are installing popper,jquery and bootstrap. for example

```
//package.json
"dependencies": {
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1"
}
```

and in the
//`angular.json`

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

remember delete node_modules and package-lock.json if you are modifying the file package. and at the end re install all again with npm install